# Loading big dataset from SSD

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

We are given a set of `recordids`[~200k] - details corresponding to the records are to be loaded from SSD(~400G) for analysis and aggregation.

Since we are new to Spark, following are the queries we had:

1. Do we feed in the input ids to a single spark driver with `x` number of partitions specified? Will the driver take care of reading and transmitting the data corresponding to each partition over network?
2. Can the worker nodes be instructed to read the data for the range corresponding to their respective partition, to prevent data transfer over wire from the driver?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Spark does that automatically. The executors only read the partitions they need to work with. If that's what you're asking.

Comment: I am confused by the response.Is it the driver or the workers who would actually do the IO from the SSD?

Answer (score 0):

You should never load large data into driver.
Spark will read the data on individual workers after partitioning the data-set.
Take a look at some examples of loading csv files